# NoClassDefFoundError: bea/jmapi/MethodProfileData when profiling app using JRockit Mission Control

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, profiling, jrockit

We're trying to profile an application running on JBoss 7.1.1, running with the JRockit VM, using Mission Control.  The management server is started using jrcmd, and we can attach using the MC console and view VM stats, etc., but if we try to use the method profiler, the app starts throwing exceptions like this:

NoClassDefFoundError: bea/jmapi/MethodProfileData

Does anybody have any ideas what would cause this?  I'm guessing it's too do with the modules system in JBoss, but would appreciate any insights that you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the answer.  I just had to add this to standalone.conf:

JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="bea.jmapi"